# Hidden input in thymeleaf with wrong value

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

in GET method I'm adding these to the model:

```
model.addAttribute("team", team);
model.addAttribute("players", team.getPlayers());
model.addAttribute("inviting", new InvitingPlayerToTeam());
```

And a fragment of view with this model:

```
<div id="news" th:fragment="playerList">
  <span>Nazwa: </span>
  <span th:text="${team.name}">nazwa teamu</span>
  <br>
  <span th:each="player : ${players}" th:utext="${player.username} + '</br>'">-</span>
  <br><br>
  <form method="POST" th:action="@{/team/invitePlayer}" th:object="${inviting}">
    Nazwa <input type="text" th:field="*{username}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{teamId}" th:value="${team.id}">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Zaproś">
  </form>
</div>
```

What is wrong? In post method field `inviting.username` has good value, but `inviting.teamId` is `0`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `th:value="${team.id}"`. You do not need to set this value again.

You should set up your form backing bean with the correct values in your controller.

`inviting.setTeamId(...)`

Comment: But .. how can I set inviting.teamId as team.id ?